# $_SESSION array is being overwritten

Tags: php, session, checkbox

Background:
I have a **checkbox** **form** with **pagination**. I have made so that each time you press the pagination buttons, whether they are **next**, **previous**, **1**,**2**,**3**,**4** or **last page** - they all POST the checkbox value from that specific page that you are on. 

The POST value is then set into a SESSION. 

 All above works fine!

Problem: 
Let say I am on page 1 of the pagination, I check one checkbox and that value, lets say the value is "111", is set into both POST and SESSION. Then I click on page 2, check one more checkbox with value "222" and then click on page 3.

 Now as soon as I click on the third link, the session value is being overwritten with 222! 

 What I want is for the array to be 111, 222. 

I want to keep the previous value from page 1 and basically just keep adding into the array until I am done, without it being overwritten.

The code is:

```
    if(isset($_POST['bundleAdId'])) 
    $_SESSION['bundleAdId'] = $_POST['bundleAdId'];
```

I understand that due to the code above, all POST values will be entered over and over again to the session whenever POST is triggered.

But how can I just ADD to the array instead of OVERWRITING?

Comment: Tried something like: `$_SESSION['bundleAdId'][] = $_POST['bundleAdId'];`? Maybe read up on [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)?

Comment: like you want to save multiple values in that session?

Comment: I tried it and It worked. wow, how can I have not seen this. I scraped the entire internet for two nights in a row on overwriting of sessions / keeping POST value in pagination and you are the first to suggest adding [ ]. Brilliant, big thanks!

Comment: @Swift123, That indicates that you aren't fully comfortable with php arrays.  It's right in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: `$_SESSION[]` is nothing more than an array. Read about [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/book.array.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make it as an array like below:-

```
$_SESSION['bundleAdId'][] = $_POST['bundleAdId'];
```

But apply check first:-

```
if(!empty($_POST['bundleAdId'])){ 
    $_SESSION['bundleAdId'][] = $_POST['bundleAdId'];
}
```

Comment: @cale_b No, with PHP loose typing and variable casting, you don't have to do that.

Comment: @cale_b  additionaly if you do that then every-time you re-initialize the array and it will become empty. so the problem remains same

Comment: Not really the way you would do it if you wanted to.  First off, no I don't think it creates a notice.  You should try it and see.  Notices are generated for attempting to access an undeclared variable, but not for initializing one, which is what is happening in this example.

Comment: Yep, you are right.  Being overly cautious! Thanks for pushing.

Comment: @AlivetoDie: none of that checking code is necessary nor an improvement from what I can see.

Comment: By definition `$_SESSION` is a superglobal **array**. PHP Is as we know a loosely typed language - you won't get a notice from the original code shared. Still, I am all for explicitly defining variables `$foo = array();`  but in this case, I think that code is overkill.